# Can't modify the font size of a UIBarButtonItem (iOS6)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdictionary, uibarbuttonitem, font-size

I'm trying to modify it, doing this:

```
button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(test:)];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]};
[button setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding custom button to rightbarbutton as below..

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourWidth, yourHeight);
[backButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"customFont" size:15.0]];
[backButton.titleLabel.text = @"yourText";
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPreviousView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

Comment: I tried this, but customButton doesn't show in customBarButton.

Comment: @Rob it works good, update post with the code, what you have tried.